# Android "application install failed"

Tags: android, failed-installation

I tried to install signed apk, it tries to install, but fail, simply saying “Application not installed.”
Here are the logs from Android Studio :

```
01-09 14:14:29.291 841-1672/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
                                            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6326)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6104)
                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3994)
                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
                                            at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                            at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
                                            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6183) 
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2695) 
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2157) 
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6326) 
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6104) 
                                            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
                                            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3994) 
                                            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

It is fresh installation. Could anyone help?

Hi all, thanks for the reply. Just to add a bit more information: the same apk can be installed successfully on all our other devices except our Samsung S5.

Comment: post your gradle as well

Comment: you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Clean Project , Build Module again and Run.